# Add a custom attribute to a Laravel / Eloquent model on load?

Tags: php, orm, laravel, eloquent

I'd like to be able to add a custom attribute/property to an Laravel/Eloquent model when it is loaded.

For instance, at the moment, in my controller I have:

```
public function index()
{
    $sessions = EventSession::all();
    foreach ($sessions as $i => $session) {
        $sessions[$i]->available = $session->getAvailability();
    }
    return $sessions;
}
```

It would be nice to be able to omit the loop and have the 'available' attribute already set and populated.

I've tried using some of the model events described in the documentation to attach this property when the object loads, but without success so far.

*Notes:*

- 'available' is not a field in the underlying table.
- `$sessions` is being returned as a JSON object as part of an API, and therefore calling something like `$session->available()` in a template isn't an option

Comment: What is the code stands for getAvailability method? If it is possible to calculate on SQL side maybe then better add a custom field into select?

Comment: use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as MysqlModel;
use Basemkhirat\Elasticsearch\Model as EsModel;

class BaseModel extends EsModel{

}

how we can change dynamically extend derive in Laravel model?? In this case, in configuration, we use elastic search if we want to change the driver to MySQL we need to manually change the driver? is there any way to change it from configuration ?

Answer (score 415, accepted):

The problem is caused by the fact that the `Model`'s `toArray()` method ignores any accessors which do not directly relate to a column in the underlying table.

As Taylor Otwell mentioned [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/112#issuecomment-12530987), "This is intentional and for performance reasons." However there is an easy way to achieve this:

```
class EventSession extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'sessions';

    public function availability()
    {
        return new Attribute(
            get: fn () => $this->calculateAvailability()
        );  
    }
}
```

**Laravel versions < 8:**

Any attributes listed in the $appends property will automatically be included in the array or JSON form of the model, provided that you've added the appropriate accessor.

```
class EventSession extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'sessions';
    protected $appends = array('availability');

    public function getAvailabilityAttribute()
    {
        return $this->calculateAvailability();  
    }
}
```

**Laravel versions < 4.08:**

The best solution that I've found is to override the `toArray()` method and either explicity set the attribute:

```
class Book extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'books';
    
    public function toArray()
    {
        $array = parent::toArray();
        $array['upper'] = $this->upper;
        return $array;
    }
    
    public function getUpperAttribute()
    {
        return strtoupper($this->title);    
    }

}
```

or, if you have lots of custom accessors, loop through them all and apply them:

```
class Book extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'books';
    
    public function toArray()
    {
        $array = parent::toArray();
        foreach ($this->getMutatedAttributes() as $key)
        {
            if ( ! array_key_exists($key, $array)) {
                $array[$key] = $this->{$key};   
            }
        }
        return $array;
    }
    
    public function getUpperAttribute()
    {
        return strtoupper($this->title);    
    }

}
```

Comment: Best question and answer for today. I was working on different implementations on how to achieve this and just before posting an question on laravel.io i found this ! yay !!!

Comment: And is there a way to don't add them to json for just some cases?

Comment: These customs attributes don't seem to appear when calling the model through a relationship. (Ex: Models\Company::with('people')). Any idea?

Comment: @JordiPuigdellívol In Laravel 5, you can use the `protected $hidden = []` to add columns/accessors to have exluded.

Comment: Good day, Sir. I am wondering if my case [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69241063/how-to-modify-a-relationship) is sort of achievable by this kind of solution. May I ask for some help from you, my kind Sir?

Comment: "use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as MysqlModel;
use Basemkhirat\Elasticsearch\Model as EsModel;

class BaseModel extends EsModel{

}




""
how we can change dynamically extend derive in Laravel model?? In this case, in configuration, we use elastic search if we want to change the driver to MySQL we need to manually change the driver? is there any way to change it from configuration ?

Answer (score 135):

The [last thing on the Laravel Eloquent doc page](https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json) is:

```
protected $appends = array('is_admin');
```

That can be used automatically to add new accessors to the model without any additional work like modifying methods like `::toArray()`.

Just create `getFooBarAttribute(...)` accessor and add the `foo_bar` to  `$appends` array.

Comment: Ah interesting. This feature has been added to Laravel since my question was posted (https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/615f16fb0407f7668536bdc0b578fea60dda5d18). This is right answer for anyone using v4.08 or higher.

Comment: This won't be available to you if you're using relationships to generate the content for your accessors. In this instance, you may have to resort to overriding the `toArray` method.

Comment: It seems as though the documentation that you referred to has been moved to here: [https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-serialization](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-serialization).

Answer (score 43):

If you rename your `getAvailability()` method to `getAvailableAttribute()` your method becomes an **accessor** and you'll be able to read it using `->available` straight on your model.

Docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators

EDIT: Since your attribute is "virtual", it is not included by default in the JSON representation of your object.

But I found this: [Custom model accessors not processed when ->toJson() called?](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/112)

In order to force your attribute to be returned in the array, add it as a key to the $attributes array.

```
class User extends Eloquent {
    protected $attributes = array(
        'ZipCode' => '',
    );

    public function getZipCodeAttribute()
    {
        return ....
    }
}
```

I didn't test it, but should be pretty trivial for you to try in your current setup.

Comment: This works in as much as it makes `->available` available on the `$session` object, but as `$sessions` gets converted directly into a JSON string (it's part of an API), there isn't a chance to use this.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how your stuff works. If `EventSession::all()` returns a JSON object from an API, you are not really using a Laravel model, right? Sorry, I'm confused on how you implemented you model.

Comment: EventSession is a standard Eloquent object (`class EventSession extends Eloquent`). `::all()` is just as an example. `EventSession::find(170071)` would be another. These are called at various points throughout SessionController (`SessionController extends \BaseController`) which would be called via URLs such as '/sessions/170071'.

Comment: I think the key may lie in Eloquent's built-in object to JSON conversion that takes place. Even if you add a custom attribute such as `public $available` to the model, this isn't shown when the object is converted.

Comment: See my edit, apparently you can force your "virtual" attribute to be return in the JSON.

Comment: As the OP found in the comments, unfortunately this doesn't seem to work in L4.

Comment: This is available since the release of Laravel 4.0.8 on October 8th, 2013. See the official docs: http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#converting-to-arrays-or-json (look for `protected $appends = array('is_admin');`)

Answer (score 31):

I had something simular:
I have an attribute picture in my model, this contains the location of the file in the Storage folder.
The image must be returned base64 encoded

```
//Add extra attribute
protected $attributes = ['picture_data'];

//Make it available in the json response
protected $appends = ['picture_data'];

//implement the attribute
public function getPictureDataAttribute()
{
    $file = Storage::get($this->picture);
    $type = Storage::mimeType($this->picture);
    return "data:" . $type . ";base64," . base64_encode($file);
}
```

Answer (score 30):

Step 1: Define attributes in `$appends`
Step 2: Define accessor for that attributes.
Example:

```php
<?php
...

class Movie extends Model{

    protected $appends = ['cover'];

    //define accessor
    public function getCoverAttribute()
    {
        return json_decode($this->InJson)->cover;
    }
```

Comment: This is lifesaver answer. Unfortunately laravel doesnt load custom attributes.

Answer (score 20):

you can use `setAttribute` function in Model to add a custom attribute

Answer (score 11):

Let say you have 2 columns named first_name and last_name in your users table and you want to retrieve full name. you can achieve with the following code :

```
class User extends Eloquent {


    public function getFullNameAttribute()
    {
        return $this->first_name.' '.$this->last_name;
    }
}
```

now you can get full name as:

```
$user = User::find(1);
$user->full_name;
```

Comment: how did you go from getFullNameAttribute to full_name?

Comment: @natghi Laravel will strip away the "get" and "Attribute" leaving us with "FullName". Then it converts that to snake_case, hence full_name

Answer (score 3):

In my subscription model, I need to know the subscription is paused or not.
here is how I did it

```
public function getIsPausedAttribute() {
    $isPaused = false;
    if (!$this->is_active) {
        $isPaused = true;
    }
}
```

then in the view template,I can use 
`$subscription->is_paused` to get the result.

The `getIsPausedAttribute` is the format to set a custom attribute,

and uses `is_paused` to get or use the attribute in your view.

Answer (score 2):

in my case, creating an empty column and setting its accessor worked fine.
my accessor filling user's age from dob column. toArray() function worked too.

```
public function getAgeAttribute()
{
  return Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $this->attributes['dateofbirth'])->age;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In new versions of laravel, custom attributes is removed from documents but still is working.
It's possible that they be completely removed in the future.
The alternate and new approach is to use `accessors`:

```
protected function name(): Attribute
{
    return Attribute::make(
        get: fn () => $this->first_name . ' ' . $this->last_name,
    );
}
```

For accessing new attributes added use them like property:

```
return [
    'name' => $user->name
];
```

[more information](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor)

Answer (score 0):

You can use map.

```
$user = User::all(); 
$user->map(function ($u) 
{ 
      $u['AttributeName'] = 'Attribute Value'; 
      return $u 
});
```

Then object user should have Attribute Name added to it