# Set new attribute to existing object

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am trying to add a new item to my object but I get an error:

Here is my code:

```
$q = Question::where('id',$id -> id)->first();
$q[]=$q->push('test',5);
dd($q);
```

Here is what this return:

> Missing argument 2 for Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::setAttribute(), called in
>   /home/client/public_html/storage/framework/compiled.php on line 10231
>   and defined

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: what is your purpose ? You're getting the "first" question, and then what you want to do ?

Comment: I want to assign to that question new random value.

Comment: to an attribute of the question ? What is the name of the attr ?

Comment: Yes I need to add new attribute...

Comment: is the attribute present on the model's table ?

Comment: No, I just want add random one...

Comment: check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17232714/add-a-custom-attribute-to-a-laravel-eloquent-model-on-load)

Answer (score 0):

According to Laravel [doc](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#insert-update-delete),

> Sometimes you may wish to save not only a model, but also all of its relationships. To do so, you may use the `push` method

Therefore push() will try to presist the attribute and it will fail because it doen't exist in your model table. Instead of using `push()`, use dynamic attributes:

```
$q->randomAttribute = "value";
```

I am not sure how you are planning to use this attribute later, maybe then I can give you a better answer.