# Laravel: Perform collection formatting after each select query

Tags: php, laravel, collections, eloquent, laravel-blade

Imagine following DB tables:

```
Clients                         Users
| Id | name  | user_id |        | ID | name   |
| -- | ----- | ------  |        | -- | ------ |
| 1  | NULL  | 1       |        | 1  | David  |
| 2  | Peter | NULL    |
```

Not each **client** is automatically **user**, but user may have client account. Users table contains only registered users, if user is client (dont have to be) the client account is created.

I have succcessfully made relations between these table is Laravel. Eloquent querying woks fine, eg.:

**clients.php**

```
public function userAcc() {
    return $this->hasOne('User', 'id', 'user_id');
}
```

**user.php**

```
public function clientAcc() {
    return $this->hasOne('Clients', 'user_id', 'id');
}
```

The problem is that when i query these tables:

```
Clients::with('userAcc')->get()
```

In view i have to make lots of ifs, like:

```
@if($client->userAcc)
    {!! $client->userAcc->name !!}
@else
    {!! $client->name !!}
@endif
```

Is there any workaround in laravel that allows me to format collections on each select query? Something like Accessor but on whole collection, so i will be able to do something like this in view:

```
{!! $client->realname !!}
```

And it writes client name from particular table.

Many thanks for any suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the Laravel way to accomplish this:

```
class Client extends Model {

public $appends = ['realname'];

public function userAcc() {
    return $this->hasOne('User', 'id', 'user_id');
}

public function getRealnameAttribute(){
    return $this->userAcc? $this->userAcc->name : $this->name;
}
```

Now it will be accessible through $client->realname and it will be included in $client->toJson() and $client->toArray()

Comment: Confirmed, working properly, thanks Jeff & @Mina Youssef

Answer (score 2):

You can make a method for that:

```
public function getName()
{
  return $this->userAcc?$this->userAcc->name:$this->name;
}
```

In your blade just call the function:

```
{{$client->getName()}}
```

Comment: Works like charm many thanks @Mina Youssef, one last thing what about AJAX calls (returning JSON) do you have any suggestions how to solve it? I mean that Clients::with('userAcc')->get()->toJson(); ...

Comment: You can take this a step further and make it an attribute, which would allow you to use it in the way you described:
`public function getRealnameAttribute(){
return $this->userAcc?$this->userAcc->name:$this->name;
}`
then you can access it using `$client->realname`

@SirInfant You can also access this using the toJson function by adding the appends attribute to the model. `public $appends = ['realname']` Then the ->toJson() function will include realname

Comment: This probably won't work, as custom accessors won't be returned in toArray(). You need to override toArray() method, and add the new custom accessor to it.

Comment: Please check this as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17232714/add-a-custom-attribute-to-a-laravel-eloquent-model-on-load