# Add a calculated field to Laravel model query

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a controller which has a query such as this one:

```
$post = Post::find($id);
$comments = $post->comments;
```

Where a post has many comments and a comment belongs to one post. The comments model has an id,comment,tag field.

What I want to do is that for any query such as this one, the model returns the fields id, comment, tag and tag_translated, where the latter is just a translation of the tag using the Lang facade.

I could solve this by using a for on the controller which iterates over the $comments and adds the field, however Ill have to do that for every controller that requires the tag_translared field. Is there a way to ask the model to include such a field?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17232714/add-a-custom-attribute-to-a-laravel-eloquent-model-on-load

see this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add a custom attribute to a Laravel / Eloquent model on load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17232714/add-a-custom-attribute-to-a-laravel-eloquent-model-on-load)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Add this in your `Comment` Model:

```
protected $appends = ['tag_translated'];

public function getTagTranslatedAttribute()
{
    return 'the translated tag';
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 14):

Yes there is? just add this to your `Comment` model

```
public function getTagTranslatedAttribute()
{
    return Lang::methodYouWish($this->tag);
}
```

then you can access this property from comment instance

```
$comment->tag_translated;
```

**EDIT**

You can modify your `toArray` method, just add it to `Comment` class

```
protected $appends = ['tag_translated'];
```

and then

```
$comment->toArray();
```

Comment: Thanks! This will retrieve only that attribute, Id like to append it to the result obtained when invoking it through its parent model as in $post->comments. Then Id like to retrieve something like id,comment,tag,translated_tag.

Comment: I'd like to lobby for this to be the accepted answer. It is much more detailed and much more user.  This is esp true after the edit.

Answer (score 6):

I was facing the same issue, and you just need to add two things:

The first one is the appends field:

```
protected $appends = ['field'];
```

The second one is the "getter":

```
public function getFieldAttribute()
```

At the end of the method name you need to add the "Attribute" suffix, and that's it.

Comment: Thanks! I learned also that if you dont add the $appends then the field is only retrieved when you specifically request for it as in $model->field.