# How to lazy load a custom attribute on a Laravel model?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Is there any possible way to lazy load a custom attribute on a Laravel model **without** loading it every time by using the `appends` property? I am looking for something akin to way that you can [lazy load Eloquent relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#lazy-eager-loading).

For instance, given this accessor method on a model:

```
public function getFooAttribute(){
    return 'bar';
}
```

I would love to be able to do something like this:

```
$model = MyModel::all();
$model->loadAttribute('foo');
```

This question is **not** the same thing as [Add a custom attribute to a Laravel / Eloquent model on load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17232714/add-a-custom-attribute-to-a-laravel-eloquent-model-on-load) because that wants to load a custom attribute on every model load - I am looking to **lazy load** the attribute only when specified.

I suppose  I could assign a property to the model instance with the same name as the custom attribute, but this has the performance downside of calling the accessor method **twice**, might have unintended side effects if that accessor affects class properties, and just feels dirty.

```
$model = MyModel::all();
$model->foo = $model->foo;
```

Does anyone have a better way of handling this?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Is this for serialization? You could use the `append()` method on the Model instance:

```
$model = MyModel::all();
$model->append('foo');
```

The `append` method can also take an array as a parameter.

Comment: Hey thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for! I'm glad Laravel has a native way to handle this. I think they only mention `appends` in the docs (and not the singular `append`) which is why I had never heard of this one.

Comment: There is a lot of cool methods I didn't know about. Diving into the Model code is very instructive and I highly recommend it to you to find great tools :)

Comment: This doesn't work as described. The `append()` method belongs to the `Model` class, but when you call `MyModel::all()` you're getting back a `Collection` object, which does not contain the `append()` method. You'd have to write: `$model->each(function($instance) { $instance->append('foo'); });`

Comment: Everytime I find my answer answered on stack, I try to find the answer in documentation too, so I get better skills in going through the documentation. For this matter I found the answer here https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection.html#method_append

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work...

```
public function loadAttribute($name) {
    $method = sprintf('get%sAttribute', ucwords($name));
    $this->attributes[$name] = $this->$method();
}
```