# Laravel order a relation by method on the model

Tags: php, laravel

Trying to think of alternate ways to get what I need from my API.

I am using Laravel Spark and have a query along the lines of:

```
$team = Team::with('users')->find($id);
```

The users relationship on the Team model is:

```
public function users()
{
   return $this->belongsToMany(
       'App\User', 'team_users', 'team_id', 'user_id'
   )->withPivot('role')->orderBy('current_active_team', 'DESC');
}
```

I am currently ordering this by a field on the users table, but I also want to order by a method on the Users model:

```
public function queueLength()
{
    // returns an integer for the users queue length
}
```

To return this data I am currently adding this under my query:

```
foreach ($team->users as $user) {
    $user->queueLength = $user->queueLength();
}
```

Is there a way I can order the $team->users by their queueLength?

Comment: Add the queue length as an attribute to your model? [See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17232714/add-a-custom-attribute-to-a-laravel-eloquent-model-on-load)

Comment: How the queueLength is? If it comes from other database table, you can do a join to allow ordering by it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution will be use collection `sortBy`.

First make queueLength as an attribute.

```
public function getQueueLengthAttribute()
{
    // returns an integer for the users queue length
}
```

Then use collection sortBy

```
$team->users->sortBy('queueLength');
```

PS: this will not be a good idea if you have huge amount of data or using pagination.