# Laravel sortBy not having any affect

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a custom attribute on my User model that's calculates the length of some other tables and returns an integer value:

```
public function GetCurrentQueueLengthAttribute()
{
    // return int
}
```

I then have an API endpoint that returns a "Team" with all its users (simple Spark pivot)

```
public function show($teamId)
{
    $query = Team::query();
    $query->with('users')->where('id', $teamId);
    $team = $query->first();

    return $team->users->sortBy('currentQueueLength');

    return $team;
}
```

The issue is that the returned data doesn't change order. There are no errors, just the same order of the users every time.

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel order a relation by method on the model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45439342/laravel-order-a-relation-by-method-on-the-model)

Comment: @ka_lin seems to be more of a follow-up than a dupe

Comment: @user3158900 Sadly not, typo on my part :(

Comment: $team->users()->sortBy('currentQueueLength') you need to force laravel to make the query

Comment: `sortBy` is not an eloquent user, try changing to `return $team->users()->sortBy('currentQueueLength');` this will first fetch the result than sort on the result set

Comment: Have you tried passing a closure to your `sortBy` call?

Comment: @Jonathon Yep, might be worth noting that even if I try to sort by the 'id' nothing still changes

Comment: Could you reverse the relation and order it directly from the database: i.e `User::where('team_id', $teamId)->orderBy('currentQueueLength')->get()`?

Answer (score 0):

The `sortBy` function is not to be mistaken by the `orderBy` function, the first one sorts a collection, the second one alters the sql of the query builder.

To be able to use the `sortBy` function one first needs to retrieve the collection. These functions can still be chained by using:

```
return $team->users()->sortBy('currentQueueLength');
```

optionally one could also use `orderByRaw` if you are willing to write a custom sql query for the sorting.

Comment: I don't think that will work because we don't want to sort on the database since this is a custom attribute.  The database has no idea about `currentQueueLength`.  We'd want to grab the collection first and sort that using PHP.