# Eloquent ORM Model Two or More Table

Tags: database, laravel, orm, eloquent, mariadb

I have a problem that I couldn't deal with it. I have a News table includes TitleID, TextID, ImageID. And three more tables Titles, Texts, Images. I want to get all of them in one model. But when I try, got result like array in array . But I want it like:

```
[ News: [ { ID, Title, Text, Image } ] ]
```

Eloquent ORM responds it like:

```
[ News: [ { ID, Title: [ID, Title], Text: [ID, Text], Image: [ID, Image] } ] ]
```

Database Structure

News =>

```html
+-----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field           | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| ID              | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| TitleID         | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| TextID          | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| ImageID         | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| CatID           | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| OlusturmaZamani | datetime    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| YayinZamani     | datetime    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| DuzenlemeZamani | datetime    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Onay            | tinyint(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Hit             | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Titles =>

```html
+------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| ID         | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| TitleText  | text    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

the other tables like title table.

Comment: Can you show the code please?

Comment: Seems like you need a classic SQL join to me

Comment: I think you need to declare the relationships between your News model and the rest of your models (Title, Text and Image). Then you will need to [append](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json) the `title`, `text` and `image` attributes to your News model.

Comment: To start with, why would you separate title or text from news table? Do you think many news can have the same text or title?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try eager loading.

If you have created relationships among News, Titles, Text and Image tables, you can load the relationship models by [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading).

```
$news = News::with('title','text','image)->find(1);
```

Comment: I already tried but it gives array in array. I want it as object of single news.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you've extracted Title and Text to their own table?

A solution for you would be something like what you see in this post:

[Add a custom attribute to a Laravel / Eloquent model on load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17232714/add-a-custom-attribute-to-a-laravel-eloquent-model-on-load)

Tweaked for your example:

Assume you changed the relationShip to "titleTable", just to avoid collision

```
class News extends Eloquent {

    protected $appends = array('title');

    public function getTitleAttribute()
    {
        return $this->titleTable->TitleText;  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like that ORM "over-normalizes".  There is no reasonable reason for *news* attributes such as title, text, and image to be put in separate tables `JOINed` by an "id".

"Eager loading" sounds like a kludge to make it feel like the columns are in the `News` table when they aren't.  This leads to unnecessary inefficiencies.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I agree with you now. It will give inefficiencies.

Comment: The ORM doesn't make you overnormalize.  That was a design decision made by the person that wrote the code..

Comment: @ChrisPhillips - Thanks for the comment.  Can you give some keywords that characterize the decision?  That way I can say "..." instead of "over-normalize".  (This is not the only Question like this.)

Comment: @RickJames  Oh, I think "over-normalizes" would be a good description. The table structure is "over-normalized", not the ORM itself.  "eager loading" is something you'd use if a record has an associated model you know you are going to be looking at in the results (eg user::with('profile')). It allows the ORM to make a more efficient query up front.