# How to reverse order of user name into last name first name and then orderBy name in laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.5

I have a **name field** in users table. I am storing **full name in single field** with first name first then last name.

What I want to do is to change the order to last name appearing first and then first name when I call `$user->nameRev` and orderBy the new name in laravel.

I already use `$user->name` in many places so cannot change that therefore I want `$user->nameRev` to reverse the name and use it in orderBy queries

How do I achieve this ?

Comment: So how do you decide which part of full name is first and second?

Comment: well the name entered is assumed to be first name then last name. So I want to reverse it when I call $user->nameRev

Comment: If your single field value is `John Smith` okay, you explode by space and reverse. And if field value is `Jon Paul Jones` - how do you process it?

Comment: name field will only have two words: first name and last name

Comment: So create a function `nameRev()` in your user model and use it.

Comment: Similar problem here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17232714/add-a-custom-attribute-to-a-laravel-eloquent-model-on-load

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add a custom attribute to a Laravel / Eloquent model on load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17232714/add-a-custom-attribute-to-a-laravel-eloquent-model-on-load)

Comment: the cleanest way is to break your name field to first_name, middle_name and last_name
so you dont have to write dirty code anymore.
then you can solve your problem with less effort.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this can be help you.

```
Public function reversName()
 {
    $user = Auth::user();
    $str = $user->name;
    list($first, $last) = (explode(" ",$str));
    $nameRev = $last. ''. $first;
    $user->nameRev = $nameRev;

    $user->save() ;

 // Or

    DB::table(users)->where('user_name')->insert($nameRev);
   ... 
  }
```