# Laravel 5.5 - How can I add a custom value to Auth::user() after successfully login

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I want to add a custom value (role) to `Auth::user()` after successful login.

I added following code in **\App\User**

```
protected $attributes = ['role'];
protected $appends = ['role'];

public function getRoleAttribute() 
{
    return $this->attributes['role'];
}    

public function setRoleAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['role'] = strtolower($value);
}
```

and I set role from Auth\LoginController

```
 function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
    { 
         //I find $position based on some calculation
         if($position == 1)
         {
             Auth::user()->role = 'director';
             return redirect('supervisors');
         }
   }
```

I want to get role in different pages like `$role = Auth::user()->role;` (but this returns error)

how can I achieve this?

Comment: What is the exact error message you are receiving? Without this we cannot really help you. Please post the contents of your error message.

Comment: When I try to access the role value from a controller (Auth::user()->role) I get the "Undefined index: role"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution myself.

Since I have to use the 'role' value in different controllers and there is no column in database table to keep the value I had to use session to store the value.

I set role value in session when user is authenticated at **Auth\LoginController**

```
function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
    if(xxxxx)
    {
        if(xxxx)
        {
            Auth::user()->role = 'director';
        }
        else
        {
            Auth::user()->role = 'manager';              
        }
    }
}
```

In **App\User**

```
public function getRoleAttribute() 
{
    return Session::get('role', null);
}

public function setRoleAttribute($value)
{
    Session::put('role', $value);
}
```

Now I can access the role value from anywhere using the following code

```
Auth::user()->role
```

Answer (score 0):

first get user details and then update that user detais like

```
$user = User::findOrFail(Auth::user()->id);
$user->role  = "director";
$user->save();
```

try this code

Comment: thanks for your answer but I don't have 'role' column in users table. role is a custom attribute, I need to set it after user login.

Comment: i think you can achive this by using one variable in your user model

Comment: and after login you can access that variable and set it's value whatever you want

Comment: please refer this link this will sure help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17232714/add-a-custom-attribute-to-a-laravel-eloquent-model-on-load