# How to add attribute to Eloquent collection?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

In `Message.php` model:

```
    public function getAudioUrlAttribute()
    {
        return \Storage::disk('public')->url('audio/' . $this->audio);
    }
```

in `MessageController.php`

```
        $messages = Message::select('id', 'role', 'content', 'audio')->get();
        $messages = $messages->map(function($message) {
            return $message->only('id', 'role', 'content', 'audio_url');
        });
        return ['messages' => $messages];
```

how to add `audio_url` to the return data elegantly? This is the only way I know, is there a better one?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add a custom attribute to a Laravel / Eloquent model on load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17232714/add-a-custom-attribute-to-a-laravel-eloquent-model-on-load)

Answer (score 1):

In your '**Message.php**' model, you can define an accessor for the '**audio_url**' attribute like this:

```
public function getAudioUrlAttribute()
{
    return \Storage::disk('public')->url('audio/' . $this->audio);
}
```

By naming the method **getAudioUrlAttribute**, Laravel will automatically append the **audio_url** attribute to your **Message** model whenever you retrieve it.

Then, in your **MessageController**.php, you can simply retrieve the messages without manually selecting the attributes:

```
$messages = Message::all();
return ['messages' => $messages];
```

Now, when you access the **audio_url** attribute on a **Message** model, Laravel will automatically call the **getAudioUrlAttribute** method, and you'll have the URL without the need for explicit mapping.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$messages = Message::select('id', 'role', 'content', 'audio')->get()->append('AudioUrl');
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the audio URL of a message without using the `append` property in the model, use `$message->audioUrl`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to append attribute globally,

In `Message.php` model:

```
protected $appends = array('audio_url');
public function getAudioUrlAttribute()
{
    return \Storage::disk('public')->url('audio/' . $this->audio);
}
```

If you want to append it on specific time,

```
$messages->append('audio_url');
```

Answer (score -1):

Your current approach of using the `map` function to add the `audio_url` attribute to the Eloquent collection is perfectly fine, and it's a common way to transform and add attributes to collections in Laravel. However, if you're looking for an alternative or more concise way to achieve the same result, you can consider using Eloquent's `append` property.

Here's how you can do it:

1. In your `Message.php` model, define an `appends` property that includes the `audio_url` attribute:

```php
class Message extends Model
{
    // ...

    protected $appends = ['audio_url'];

    public function getAudioUrlAttribute()
    {
        return \Storage::disk('public')->url('audio/' . $this->audio);
    }

    // ...
}
```

By adding `'audio_url'` to the `appends` property, you're telling Laravel to automatically append the `audio_url` attribute to the JSON representation of the model.

2. In your `MessageController.php`, simply retrieve the messages without specifying the attributes you want to select:

```php
$messages = Message::all(); // This retrieves all columns from the table
return ['messages' => $messages];
```

Now, when you return the `$messages` collection, it will automatically include the `audio_url` attribute without the need for additional transformation using `map`.

This approach keeps your code more concise and takes advantage of Laravel's built-in functionality for appending attributes to model instances when they are serialized to JSON.